# Edit binary file using R

Tags: c, r, shiny, binaryfiles

I need to edit an existing binary file using R, the binary file can be downloaded here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1a4mb6pj5heju4t/CAMTRAP.CTC?dl=0.

The original file was written in C, with the following structure:

```
typedef struct  {
 int8 RTCMonth; // RTC properties used to set camera clock
 int8 RTCDay;
 int8 RTCHour;
 int8 RTCMin;
 int8 RTCSec;
 int16 RTCYear;
 int8 setRTC; // set = 1 to set the RTC using the RTC properties
 int8 softwareVersion[51];
 int16 flashImagesPerTrigger;
 int16 daylightImagesPerTrigger;
 int16 delayBetweenImagesFlash;
 float delayBetweenImagesDaylight;
 int32 imageCounter;
 int8  clearImageCounter; // set = 1 to clear image counter
 int16 SPARE0;
 int8 cameraID[9];
 int8 usbBackupMethod; // 0=FULL, 1=INCREMENTAL, 2=FULL PLUS DELETE
 int16 flashImageBrightness; // 0=NORMAL, 1=BRIGHT, 2=BRIGHTEST
 int8  RESERVED1[32];
 int8  RESERVED2;
 int8 logFileExtention[3];
 int8 SPARE1[3];
 int8 RESERVED3;
 float flashCrossoverCdS; 
 int8  setFlashCrossoverCdS; // = 1 to set
 float SPARE3;   
 int8  SPARE4;
 float AspectRatio;    
 int8 setAspectRatio; // = 1 to set
 int8 derivativeClipNormal;  
 int8 setDerivativeClipNormal; // = 1 to set
 int8 purgeLogFile; // = 1 to purge log file
 int8 SPARE5; 
 float chargeFlashTarget;   
 int8 setChargeFlashTarget; // = 1 to set
 int8 jpegCompressionRatio; // 12=LOW, 24=MEDIUM, 40=HIGH
 int8 setJpegCompressionRatio; // = 1 to set
 int8 setExifComment; // = 1 to set
 int8 exifComment[50];
 //GPS parms and location data 
 int8 setRTCFromGPS; // = 1 to set
 int8  RESERVED4;
 int16 utcOffsetHours; // local UTC time adjustment
 int16 utcOffsetMinutes;
 int8 adjustRtcForDaylightSavings; // set = 1 to enable
 int8 daylightSavingsBeginMonth;
 int8 daylightSavingsBeginDay;
 int8 daylightSavingsEndMonth;
 int8 daylightSavingsEndDay;
 int8 clearGpsData; // set = 1 to clear GpsData
 int32  latitudeRef;
 int32  latitudeDegrees;
 int32  latitudeMinutes;
 int32  latitudeSeconds;
 int32  longitudeRef;
 int32  longitudeDegrees;
 int32  longitudeMinutes; 
 int32  longitudeSeconds; 
 int8   altitudeRef; 
 int32  altFromMSL; 
 int8   RESERVED5;
 int8   setGpsLocation;  // = 1 to set
 int8   encryptJpgFiles; // set = 1 to enable
 int8   RESERVED6;
 float  bootLoaderVersion;
 int8   powerLock; // set = 1 to enable
 int8   stealthLedMode; // 0=OFF, 1=No LED indications after initialization, 2=No LED's, extended day, 3=NoLEDs, Extended Day, No Flash Pics
 int8   RESERVED7;
 float RESERVED8;
 float RESERVED9; 
 int32 V4SPARE0[2];
 int8  sdCardCleanup; // = 1 to set
 int8  enableTrafficBlocking; // = 1 to set
 int8  V4SPARE[22];
 int8  serverHostname[40];
 int8  serverPort[6];
 int8  networkAPN[40];
 int8  apnUserID[16];
 int8  apnPassword[16];
 int8  apnOperNum[9];
 int8  hardwareTag[10];
 int16 HourForLogUpload; // 0-23 (set > 23 to disable)
 int8  FlashlightMode; // = 1 to set
 int16 MaxDailyImageUploads;
 int8  disableVehicleDetection; // = 1 to set 
 int8  disableHumanDetection; // = 1 to set
 int8  initialLEDactiveMinutes;
 int32 RESERVED10;
 int8  synchCameraClockWithServer; // = 1 to set  
 int8  sendImageWithLogFileUpload; // = 1 to set
 int8  RESERVED11[545];
}SYS_CONFIG; //1024bytes
```

I'm not that familiar with binary files, but according to the author, the members are laid out little endian, following a default member alignment (i.e., there is a padding byte to keep the "short" struct member properly aligned on a 2-byte boundary, such that whenever an "int" or "short" follows a "char" a padding byte is inserted to maintain correct alignment).

I'm basically writing a Shiny app that'll allow users to edit their own binary file (which follows the same structure as in the example). Only trouble is I haven't had any luck navigating this binary file. So far I've tried using readBin and writeBin, and although readBin allows me to view certain aspects of the file, I can't seem to figure out the pattern of these data.

I'm not looking for someone to write my code for me, but please can someone assist in explaining how I can use R to edit certain aspects of this particular binary file. For instance, let's say I wanted to change the "exifComment" to include some random text. How do I locate that section of the binary file, and then apply and save new data to it? Is this even possible in R?

Thanks in advance!

PS - apologies if I've left out any important info, but this is all I have to work with.

Comment: First, open a read-binary connection to the file with `file`: `con<-file("path/to/file",open="rb")`; then see `?readBin` to read values from it. Pay attention to the `size` argument: R deals only with 4-bytes integer and 8-bytes doubles. So, you have to specify the size for each value you read. For instance, the first value is read with `readBin(con,"integer", n=1, size=1)`. Once you read the values, you can modify them with R.

Comment: Thanks, @nicola. I forgot to mention the following: int8 = one byte; int16 = two bytes; int32 = four bytes ; float = four bytes. Is this an issue if R only deals with 4-byte integers? I actually have been doing exactly what you suggest in your comment (i.e., make the connection, then read value by value), but as I work through the values, I start to get strange results, which make me think I'm not mapping the file correctly. Or perhaps I'm getting confused with the padding structure?